# printing the proper aws cloudwatch properly for mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose

I am using `mongoose` and making use of `mongoose.set('debug', true)` . Through the query string is printed correct in the local machine, but  `aws cloudwatch` log has query string in `utf-8` chracter. Here is the sample.

```
\u001b[0;36mMongoose:\u001b[0m promotions_user.findAndModify({ promo_id: \u001b[
```

How I can transform `utf-8` into simple view-able log for debugging.

Is it possible to remove `ANSI character` in the logs?

Comment: You could provide a different logger function instead of `true`. The issue is essentially that the output does not accept the ANSI sequences for rendering the colors. So you either look at the log through a terminal device that understands the ANSI sequences, or you define a custom logger to simply output without the ANSI sequences. Which question are you actually asking? So those are not actually UTF-8 and that's not the issue.